# Arithmetic with the natural log

Tags: logarithms

We have:

$$ \ln(p^3 + 4) - \ln(4) = 2$$

What I did is:

$$ \ln (p^3 + 4) = \ln(4) + \ln(e^2)$$

$$p^3 + 4 = 4 + e^2$$

$$ p = e^{2/3}$$

Why is this incorrect?

Comment: The mistake is in going from $\log4+\log e^2$ to $4+e^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct your mistake using this equality
$$\log (a)+\log(b)=\log(ab)$$

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that rule.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

$$\log(p^3+4)-\log 4=2\iff \log\frac{p^3-4}4=2\iff \frac{p^3-4}4=e^2\ldots\ldots$$